# How to construct a call to a method using dynamic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamictype

Hi I have a namespace with a lot of classes and all of them has a method Destroy(int id)
I want to call that method using dynamic word.

Here is my example:

```
public bool DeleteElement<T>(T tElement)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    dynamic element = tElement;
    var id = element.Id;

    //until here everything is fine
    //here I want to say 
    (namespace).myClassName.Destroy(id);
    //the name of  myClassName is like t.ToString()
}
```

I can avoid namespace including a using at the top. The idea is to call that static method using dynamic, not Reflection, please see that Destroy is a static method of T. I need something like this T.Destroy(id)

Comment: Which framework are you *actually* targeting? `dynamic` is not available in C# 3.0. Sounds like a good time for an interface... (and associated generic type constraint)

Comment: I put the question to people in C# 3.0 because someone could know about this

Comment: Ok, but it changes what we can use. We still need to know what framework elements are allowed.

Comment: @Zinov, people who follow the `c#-3.0` tag usually follow the `c#` tag as well, so you don't really need to include all versions ;)

Answer (score 5):

If `Destroy(int id)` is a static method, couldn't you create an instance method that would call the static one?

```
public void Destroy()
{
    ThisClass.Destroy(this.Id);
}
```

You could then define an `IDestroyable` interface implemented by all these classes:

```
interface IDestroyable { void Destroy(); }
```

And then modify your `DeleteElement` method as follows:

```
public bool DeleteElement<T>(T tElement) where T : IDestroyable
{
    tElement.Destroy();
}
```

No need to use `dynamic` here... Actually, using `dynamic` in this situation is often an indication of bad design. It's quite rare to actually *need* `dynamic` except in the scenarios for which it was created (e.g. interop with dynamic languages)

(If the classes are generated but they have the `partial` modifier, you can declare the new method in another file that is not touched by the generator)

---

EDIT: if the classes are generated and are not `partial`, you can't modify them... So another solution would be to use reflection; I know you want to avoid that (for performance reasons I assume), but you can limit the performance impact by doing the reflection only once for each type: you just need to create and cache a delegate for each type.

```
class DestroyHelper<T>
{
    static readonly Action<int> _destroy;
    static readonly Func<T, int> _getId;
    static DestroyHelper()
    {
        var destroyMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("Destroy", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        _destroy = (Action<int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<int>), destroyMethod);
        var getIdMethod = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id").GetGetMethod();
        _getId = (Func<T, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, int>), getIdMethod);
    }

    public static void Destroy(T element)
    {
        _destroy(_getId(element));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nop all the classes are generated, every time that something change I need to fix all code putting the inheritance to IDestroyable, this is not the approach that I am looking for

Comment: @Zinov, I assume you have no control over the generation of these classes? And are they by chance declared as `partial`? If they are, my solution can still work.

Comment: Again: The idea is to call that static method using dynamic, not Reflection. I have the solution using Reflection, I want to know if it is possible to do this using dynamic

Comment: @Zinov, I wasn't suggesting to use reflection (in my original answer). I don't think it's possible to call static methods with `dynamic`; I edited my answer to provide a solution that uses reflection but limits the performance impact.

Comment: Just checked: I can confirm that it's not possible to call a static method on an instance with `dynamic`. It gives an exception with the same message the compiler would give if you did that on a statically typed variable.

Comment: Can you put the example that you used?

Comment: @Zinov, here it is: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/b89b0bce8b97640b5b6b (it's a LinqPad query)

Comment: @Levesque in your example you are trying to call to Bar() method like not static. foo on this case is an instance, and Foo class does not have Bar() method like not static. That's why you are getting an error. You need to call to a "typeof(Foo)".Bar(). But here typeof will return a Type, and again we will call the method using Reflection with this approach. That is not what I need

Comment: @Zinov, I know, but `dynamic` doesn't provide a way to express static method calls as `TypeName.MethodName`. There are workarounds, but they're not very convenient.

Comment: As for reflection: how do you think `dynamic` works? When working with objects that are not intrinsically dynamic, it uses reflection, because it's the only way to access members that are not known statically. Of course, it does it in a very optimized way, using caches and such, but it *has* to use reflection. If you think you can make your code more efficient with `dynamic` than with reflection, think again ;)

Comment: if I use IDestroyable as part of my solution, it will not work because Destroy as I said is a static method, and you can't put a static method to an interface. The necessity of dynamic is just to know how to call a static method with dynamic. On MSDN reference they do not say nothing about this. And of course dynamic needs to use reflection to work, because is on runtime when it has all the information about the instance.However if I can't make my code more efficient using dynamic I need to use reflection, is just to avoid more lines of code.

Comment: @Zinov, I wasn't suggesting to put the static method in the interface. Here's an example of what I meant: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/c8ba98a693ab0e9412a1

Comment: Generated part has the Destroy as static
 
partial class MyClass
{
    public static void Destroy(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
}

Comment: @Zinov, yes, so what's the problem? The code I linked to is based on that assumption. You can have two different methods with the same name, as long as they have different parameters

Comment: Thanks, I just read it, but still I am wondering the solution with dynamic(if "exists"). I had a solution like yours with Reflection https://gist.github.com/zinov/fb0c0d2512336332925d . Thanks in advance

Comment: @Zinov, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do it with dynamic. The interface approach is probably the best, since it only uses the static type system and doesn't involve reflection.